# DDD - what is proper code structure

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, directory-structure, legacy

I am working on legacy project trying to improve project structure. My question is how should I organize code structure. I see two options:

> #1 business-domain / layer

```
app/
----accout/
--------application/
--------domain/
--------infrastructure/
----client/
--------application/
--------domain/
--------infrastructure/
----transfer/
--------application/
--------domain/
--------infrastructure/
```

> or #2 layer / business-domain

```
app/
----application/
--------account/
--------client/
--------transfer/
----domain/
--------account/
--------client/
--------transfer/
----infrastructure/
--------account/
--------client/
--------transfer/
```

Which approach would fit better for legacy project? Which is preferable from your experience?

From my point of view, #1 will enable system decoupling during further refactoring. On the other hand, #1 seems easier to achieve for legacy project.

Comment: How does DDD come into picture when you write about directory structure?

Comment: Ok then, in your DDD projects how do you organize code structure? I guess you do not want to keep all building blocks in one package

Comment: Well currently how you asked is pretty much opinion based, and not sure it will help future visitors since all my projects structures are different. The basic difference is that each projects are _driven_ by different business use cases which are the solution space in code, therefore I try to organize them according to the ubiquitous language that is driven by the force of sub-domains and bounded contexts. I can't give good advices and "best practices" since these does not exist. Just do it as it conforms you and your team to help the development cycle be as fast and effective as it can help.

Comment: I don't see anything related to interfaces. Interfaces are crucial to decouple components.

Answer (score 5):

Accordingly to book [ddd in php](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php) you can create modules, and in this case it will looks like:

```
└──src
   ├── Application
   ├── Domain
   │   └── Model
   │       ├ Account
   │       ├ Client
   │       └ Transfer
   └── Infrastructure
```

But, if you consider to create microservices in feature (in case when your project is really huge) you can follow your option **#1**, because it will be easier to split them to separate projects.